# Count number of rows that are at the minimum of a group MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains all the distinct names from another table, and then a column that holds the minimum value that the name received. For example, the table looks like this:

```
table1
Name | min_value
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 4
```

The original table looks like this:

```
table2
Name | value
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 4
a    | 2
c    | 8
a    | 1
```

I want to return the number of times that the minimum value occurs within the original table. So, in this example it would return something like this:

```
output_table
Name | times_at_min
a    | 2
b    | 1
c    | 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
SELECT m.Name,
       min_value,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN m.value = min_value THEN 1 END) As times_at_min
FROM mytable AS m
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Name, 
          MIN(value) AS min_value       
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY Name ) AS g
ON m.Name = g.Name
GROUP BY Name
```

In a subquery you select `MIN(value)` per `Name`. Joining with the derived table of this subquery, you can perform *conditional aggregation* so as to calculate the number of times the minimum value appears in the original table.

[**Fiddle demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f5d6/1)

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain which table you are referring to with mytable? That's my fault, I should have labeled the tables in the question.

Comment: @honeybadger I refer to your original table (fiddle demo makes this clear I think). The result of the query contains both `min_value` and `times_at_min` fields.

Comment: @honeybadger Glad I was able to help. You substitute derived table `g` by `table1`, as long as this table holds a *predefined* set of `Name` values and their corresponding minimum values.